# Balance 2 sets of values item by item

Tags: python, list

my question may seem similar to others but I haven't found anything remotely close to what I need yet (I'm still searching around in case). I have a project (details on the project aren't necessary) when I find myself with a finite list of negative values and 2 other finite sets of positive values (floating point numbers). Take the example sets below:

```
negative_values = [-0.246497, -0.341068]
positive_values_1 = [0.522148, 0.923764, 0.112573, 0.401668]
positive_values_2 = [0.281474]
```

These sets can range in size (empty to size N). What I need to do is take the values in the first positive set and try (might not be possible depending on the set) to make the values in the negative set 0 by adding them together value by value.

If it isn't possible with only the first, then use the second set and if it still isn't possible, then make as many of the values in 'negative_values' 0 as possible.

With the above sets, this would render something like this:

```
def cancelOut(negative_values, positive_values_1, positive_values_2):
    # Algorith doing something

new_negative_values = [0, 0]
new_positive_values_1 = [0, 0.858347, 0.112573, 0.401668]
new_positive_values_2 = [0.281474]
```

What has happened is that the first values in positive_values_1 made the first value in negative_value 0 and increased the second one closer to 0. Then part of the second value in positive_values_1 made the second value in negative_value 0 and then the algorithm is done. I simply want to add the values in the positive sets to the values in negative_value one by one until they are all 0 or until the positive_value sets are all 0.

I don't know if there's a simple way to do this or if I need to specifically iterate through each set value by value and calculate what I want.

Thanks in advance everyone!

Comment: What do you mean by `canceled out`? Are you looking for items of equal magnitude but opposite sign?  If you have tried something, you should add it to your question and tell us why it isn't working. - [mcve] - your example data should allow us to test any solutions

Comment: We should be able to copy and paste your examples and use them to test solutions. Those `...`'s don't help - the easier you make it the more answers you might get.

Comment: Not necessarily equal magnitude but of opposite sign yes. I haven't tried anything code wise, what I thought of doing was adding the positive to the negative one by one but I want to know if there's an efficient way of doing so. The data given is enough to do what I want :)

Comment: It is unclear what **cancel out** means in this case if the values are not of equal magnitude. DV until clarified.

Comment: Being an `...absolute lover of programming...` your best bet is to try something, anything and try to get it to work. Once you get it too work then you can worry about efficiencies/optimizations - many times it will be *good enough*.  If you get stuck trying to make it work - ask more specific questions here.  Posting your code also helps us figure out what you are trying to do if the text description isn't precise.

Comment: Is the question clearer after the edit ? I don't currently have access to my code which is why I'm asking this on mobile, sorry for not explaining this. I will be coding this tomorrow hopefully.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a place to start - it will be an exercise in logic and keeping track of things.

```
a = negative_values
b = positive_values_1
c = positive_values_2
```

Start with the first items of `a` and `b`.

```
add the a and b item together  
   if the result is > 0 change a's item to 0  
      and get a's next item to use in the next iteration  
          use the result for the b item in the next iteration
   if the result is 0 change a and b's item to 0  
       and get the next items from a and b to use in the next iteration  
   if the result is < 0 change b's item to zero  
       and get b's next item for use in the next iteration
           use the result for the a item in the next iteration   
if you get a StopIteration for a you are done
    make the current item/index of b (or c) = the result
if you get a StopIteration for b, switch to c
if you get a StopIteration for c you are done
    make the current item/index of a = the result
repeat
```

Comment: Thanks! This seems (at least text wise) like what I'm trying to do. I'll try this as soon as possible and confirm this works or not :D

Comment: I tried to upvote but the downvote from dawg means I can't, sorry.

Comment: np, i made it a wiki so I don't get the votes anyway :)